# When a cell equals a certain value auto populate today's date in adjacent cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of sales leads, where we are hoping to track if the lead has replied to us and if so on which date on top of that I am also hoping to track if they have converted and if so on which date.

We manually enter into a cell 'Y' upon receiving a reply or conversion, but I would like the cell beside it to auto populate the date of when we put in the 'Y'.

So far I have been able to find a script which can do this for one column on a sheet, but I am actually trying to create a script that can do this for multiple columns on multiple tabs.

Hopefully this screenshot helps explain:

https://screenshot.click/05_20-mfohy-1jfi2.jpg

I found this script which works great for one column but I having difficulty making it work for two columns:

```
function onEdit(event){
var ColAF = 32; // Column Number of "AH"

var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColAF) {
// An edit has occurred in Column AF
var state = changedRange.getValue();
var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColAF+1);
var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time
// depending on the selected value
switch (state) {
  case "y":
    // Write timestamp into adjacent cell
    adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
    break;
  case "Y":
    // Write timestamp into adjacent cell
    adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
    break;
  default:
    adjacent.setValue("");
    break
 }
}
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NB-a2Cgm1hchuEoQc3zCBtiaOdqsKHnQF41v5vYfkX4/edit?usp=sharing) for a sample.

Comment: the only way done is with script

Comment: Totally, I have been trying to write a script to make this work but have been having difficulty

Answer (score 0):

In your sample when I changed the `32` to `4` it works as you expect. Your var is named `colAF` which is index 32 but your comment says `AH` which is index 34.

```
var ColAF = 32; // Column Number of "AH"
```

Double check your ranges.

Try adding some Logging to see what is happening.

```
function onEdit(event){
var ColAF = 4; // Column Number of "AH"
var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
Logger.log(changedRange.getColumn());
Logger.log(changedRange.getColumn() == ColAF);
if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColAF) {
```

Edit your code similar to the above, save the code then make a change. To view the log go to 'View' -> 'Logs' in the debugger.

In the above the output of the log is

```
  [18-01-08 19:51:42:815 ICT] 4.0
  [18-01-08 19:51:42:816 ICT] true
```

If it doesn't solve the problem please paste your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the 32/34 was taken from the real sheet that I was working with, but for this purpose it should have been 1 & 3. Anyways, I was finally able to figure it out, it was much simpler than i originally thought I will paste the answer below;

```
function onEdit(e) {
if ([1,3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1 || ['y','Y'].indexOf(e.value) == -1) return;
e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyyy"))}
```